# Rails scaffolding not generating options menu appears

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

Here is step by step what I did.

```
cd ~/rails_projects 
rails new demo_app1
cd demo_app1
```

(modified my gem file for rails 3.2.13.     Ssqlite3 to 1.3.5      sass-rails to 3.2.4          coffee rails to 3.2.2     uglier to 1.2.3      jquery-rails to 2.0.1        and pg to 0.12.2)

then bundle update

```
bundle install --without production

git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

then rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string

but it doesn't generate the scaffolding all I get is the options menu which is posted below.

```
Chris-Schusters-MacBook-Pro:demo_app1 schust49$ rails generate scaffold user name:string email:string
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: /Users/schust49/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                 # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                 # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Where am I going wrong and how do I fix this to make it scaffold?

Comment: can you try without Gemfile Edit?

Comment: unfortunately I need the gem file edits. I am following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial book (teaching myself how to code before i enter a dev boot camp for ruby on rails)

Comment: still you struggling with that issue?

Comment: yes havent been able to resolve it yet sadly. Im not sure why it is not recognizing the scaffold command. One of my coworkers has suggested to try  rails generate scaffold User entering that and seeing if the scaffold will generate, but ill have to do that when i get home as i didnt bring my home computer to the office today.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install the `gem 'sqlite3' add that in gemfile

And then bundle install......

one more thing firstly if you have RVM insalled on your machine then select a ruby version with rvm and after that

check the ruby version

```
ruby -v
```

and rails version

```
rails -v
```

if both give you version which you have used in your application and bundle complete then it will not give the above options and create the model

Comment: yes I have RVM installed, and I updated the bundle and installed it, and both ruby and rails and all gem file edits are using the versions I would like (checked using ruby -v and rails -v, but the issue still persists.......

Comment: one more thing did you successfully created the database for that.